# Dice game Probability Theory

Tags: probability

In a certain game, a player rolls two dice and wins if he scores 9 or more. If he fails the first time, he gets a
second chance to roll 9 or more. What is the probability of his winning?

I did the following:
10/36*10/36+10/36=115/324

The answer from my professor is 155/324, what did I wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Winning means that either he wins the first round, or he loses the first round and wins the second one. If you denote by $p$ the probability to win a round, then you have the following :

• Probability of winning the first round: $p$, by definition

• Probability of losing the first round and winning the second one: $(1-p)\times p$.

So the answer is $p+(1-p)\times p=p\times(2-p)$.

But you seem to have found that the formula was $p^2+p$. That would be the sum of the probability of winning two rounds in a row and the probability of winning one round. There's now way this could be interpreted as the probability of a single event because for $p$ close to $1$ this implies a probability bigger than 1.

Since $p=\frac{10}{36}$, so the answer is indeed $\frac{10}{36}\times(2-\frac{10}{36})=\frac{155}{324}$.